# Why is Prisma asking for attributes with default values?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I'm creating a NestJS project with PostgreSQL and Prisma. In the database, the Book entity has the following attributes:

1. bookId
2. bookTitle
3. coverUrl
4. bookStatus

Both the bookId and bookStatus have a default value. gen_random_uuid and 'active'::character varying, respectively. Therefore, I'm able to create a book just by providing the title and the cover URL. However, I'm not able to do so in my NestJS project with Prisma, even know the schema seems to be right:

```
model Book {
  bookId           String             @id(map: "pk_book") @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.VarChar(80)
  bookTitle        String             @unique(map: "unique_name_books") @db.Citext
  coverUrl         String?            @db.VarChar(100)
  bookStatus       String             @default("active") @db.VarChar(10)
  book_author      Book_author[]
  collections_book Collections_book[]
}
```

Here is the code that tries to create the book just by providing the title and the cover URL:

```
const bookId:BookIdDto = await this.prisma.book.create({
   data:{
          bookTitle:data.bookTitle,
          coverUrl:null,
         }
   });

return bookId;
```

Here is the error I get from VScode:

```
Type '{ bookTitle: string; coverUrl: null; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<BookCreateInput, BookUncheckedCreateInput> & BookUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & BookCreateInput)'.
  Type '{ bookTitle: string; coverUrl: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Without<BookUncheckedCreateInput, BookCreateInput> & BookCreateInput'.
    Type '{ bookTitle: string; coverUrl: null; }' is missing the following properties from type 'BookCreateInput': bookId, bookStatusts(2322)
index.d.ts(2825, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ select?: BookSelect; include?: BookInclude; data: (Without<BookCreateInput, BookUncheckedCreateInput> & BookUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & BookCreateInput); }'
(property) data: (Prisma.Without<Prisma.BookCreateInput, Prisma.BookUncheckedCreateInput> & Prisma.BookUncheckedCreateInput) | (Prisma.Without<Prisma.BookUncheckedCreateInput, Prisma.BookCreateInput> & Prisma.BookCreateInput)
The data needed to create a Book.
```

I honestly haven't tried anything at all. I'm very confused, and I do not know where to start.

I would appreciate some help to figure out why is Prisma asking for properties that should be generated automatically.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does you code editor show any types errors?

Try to run `prisma generate` and `prisma db push` first.

Comment: The problem was solved by executing prisma generate. Can you please explain to me why?